# Can we save multiple records for one customer?

Tags: sqlite, database-design, database-normalization

Hi I am developing a cross-platformm application using cordova. I have a table like this
[image]

First I need to get the data and store them in my database.Second when I select a particular customer I need to fetch that particular record and display them in the next page.
Here is a code that I have done till now,
I have created a database sqlite and a table waitlist,

```
<script>

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
     var st,et;
        var currentRow;

   function populateDB(tx) {

            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS waitlist13 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name, startdatetime,enddatetime)');
        }

          function errorCB(err) {
            alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
        }
          function errorCB1(err) {
            alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
        }

        // Transaction success callback
        //
        function successCB() {
            //var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name:"sqlite"});
            //db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
            alert("table waitlist created");
        }
         function successCB1() {
           window.location="waitlist.html";
        }



         // Cordova is ready
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name:"sqlite"});
            db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
        }

        //Insert query
        //
        function insertDB(tx) {

             tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO waitlist13 (name,startdatetime,enddatetime) VALUES ("' +document.getElementById("clienttextbox").value
                    +'","'+st+'" ,"'+et+'")');

        }

        function goInsert() {
          console.log("start time");
          console.log(st);

          var currentdate = new Date();
          var enddatetime = currentdate.getHours() + ":"+ currentdate.getMinutes() + ":"+currentdate.getSeconds();
                et=enddatetime;
                console.log(enddatetime);
                console.log("end time");
          console.log(et);
           var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name:"sqlite"});
            db.transaction(insertDB, errorCB1, successCB1);
        }



  </script>
```

Here I need to change my table structure as,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS waitlist13 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name, waitingtime,ticketid,ticketname);
```

Then I need to insert multiple values in insert like this,

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO waitlist13 (name,waitingtime,ticketid,ticketname) VALUES ("' +document.getElementById("clienttextbox").value
                    +'","'+st+'" ,"'+et+'")');
```

How could I get the values from the table I generate and store them on respective column in database with same id? Can someone suggest me a efficient way?Can someone please help me? Thank you in advance...

Comment: So your problem is that you want to store multiple things for one customer?

Comment: Yes Can you please help me? @CL.

Comment: So Should I save my data in two different table?@CL.

Comment: A primary key is a value that identifies the record, which means it should be unique. You can do two things: add another field which holds the id of the customer, which can be repeated across several records, or create another table which pairs the (unique) ids of this table with the (unique) ids of the customers.